# python syntax error in attempt to create decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-dataclasses

I don't understand the error I'm getting in this attempted decorator
declaration and use. It's my first try so it's probably something obvious.

I define the decorator in `utils.py`, import it to `test.py` where I apply the decorator as a property of a `dataclass` and then run `test.py`.

I get this error:

```
#
#Runtime error :
#
File "/mnt/sda/hd2/projects/test/dbus/test.py", line 11
    flags: List[str]
    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is utils.py

```
# utils.py
#
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

class ImmutableFieldError(Exception):
    pass

def staticlist(default_value: List[str]) -> field:
    def setter(self, value):
        raise ImmutableFieldError("Cannot modify the static constant")
    
    return field(default_factory=lambda: default_value, init=False, repr=False, hash=False, compare=False, default=None, metadata=None, fset=setter)
```

And the test.py

```
#
# test.py
#
#!/usr/bin/python
from utils import staticlist
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass 
class Test:
  on : str
  
  @staticlist(['yes','no'])
  flags: List[str]
```

Comment: You can decorate functions and classes only.

Comment: @KlausD. Well! That was easy. Thank you,